# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 argument

Tags: c#, generics

```
   public IEnumerable<TValue> Find(IEnumerable<T> text)       

{
    var node = root;

    foreach (T c in text)
    {
        while (node[c] == null && node != root)
            node = node.Fail;

        node = node[c] ?? root;

        for (var t = node; t != root; t = t.Fail)
        {
            foreach (TValue value in t.Values)
                yield return value;
        }
    }
}

        private class Node<TNode, TNodeValue> : IEnumerable<Node<TNode, TNodeValue>>
        {
            private readonly TNode word;
            private readonly Node<TNode, TNodeValue> parent;
            private readonly Dictionary<TNode, Node<TNode, TNodeValue>> children = new Dictionary<TNode, Node<TNode, TNodeValue>>();
            private readonly List<TNodeValue> values = new List<TNodeValue>();
```

/// Constructor for the root node.

```
            public Node()
            {
            }

            public Node(TNode word, Node<TNode, TNodeValue> parent)
            {
                this.word = word;
                this.parent = parent;
            }

            public TNode Word
            {
                get { return word; }
            }


            public Node<TNode, TNodeValue> Parent
            {
                get { return parent; }
            }
```

/// Fail or fall node.

```
                public Node<TNode, TNodeValue> Fail
                {
                    get;
                    set;
                }


                public Node<TNode, TNodeValue> this[TNode c]
                {
                    get { return children.ContainsKey(c) ? children[c] : null; }
                    set { children[c] = value; }
                }


                public List<TNodeValue> Values
                {
                    get { return values; }
                }

                /// <inherit/>
                public IEnumerator<Node<TNode, TNodeValue>> GetEnumerator()
                {
                    return children.Values.GetEnumerator();
                }

                /// <inherit/>
                IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() //error thrown here - requires 1 type argument
                {
                    return GetEnumerator();
                }

                public override string ToString()
                {
                    return Word.ToString();
                }   
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help with issue. Quite new to C# and cant understand what I'm missing. On other forums people suggest to remove the word Generic from the Collections namespace, but this also doesn't work

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm quite new to the forum. On the line IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()- I get an error which requires 1 type argument. It's on the second last function from the bottom.

Comment: answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477440/2377343

Answer (score 1):

Your generic type identifiers `TValue` and `T` don't exist in that scope. Instead of

```
public IEnumerable<TValue> Find(IEnumerable<T> text)
```

Try

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(IEnumerable<T> text)
```

You can't pick and choose generic type identifiers, they need to exist in the scope they are being used to be avaliable to you. TNode and TNodeValue will both suffer from the same thing because they are not defined in the same scope.. you should post ALL of your code and format it correctly next time, by the way, as it's hard to understand whether I am seeing your whole code here (Are `TNode` and `TNodeValue` defined? Are `TValue` and `T` defined? Where is `root` coming from?)

Comment: Sorry I have added the complete code now. I appreciate your answer also, thank you.