# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> requires 1 type arguments

Tags: c#

My Code in C# is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace cs
{
    public class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable
    {
    }
```

And I got error here:

> Error  1   Using the generic type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'` requires 1 type arguments

Comment: You need IEnumerable<T> if you are making the class generic

Comment: Change it to `TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: You haven't tried resolving it's namespace?

Answer (score 41):

Interface `IEnumerable` is declared in `System.Collections`, so following should be added:

`using System.Collections;`

There is also a similar interface, `IEnumerable<T>`, which is a generic version of IEnumerable and that one is declared in `System.Collections.Generic` and that is why Visual Studio gives you such a mysterious error.

Answer (score 6):

There are two "versions" of `IEnumerable`.

One is the nongeneric [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx). This is provided *mostly* for backwards compatibility. I can't really think of a good reason to make new classes directly inherit from it.

The other is the generic one, [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0(v=vs.100).aspx). This implements `IEnumerable` as well, so it's a better choice in all cases.

When an interface has a generic overload, you need to specify that generic type parameter. In your case,

```
public class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

It's worth noting that when you implement this, you'll need to implement two methods:

```
Enumerator<T> GetEnumerator(); // From IEnumerable<T>
Enumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(); // From IEnumerable
```

It's not too unusual too return `this.GetEnumerator()` from the second one, since again, it's provided *mostly* as backwards-compatibility. You always want those two enumerators to return the same data, so that's a nice and easy solution.

Comment: The only good use I know for IEnumerable is to use it as a return type for SQL CLR functions.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious, but it is not clear to me why the generic one is better. From your answer it just looks like it is harder to use (for example needing to implement two methods).

Comment: @MikeWise using the generic version means the compiler can check types of elements for you--basically the same as any other time you'd use generics. Similarly, it also makes Linq expressions available, since they depend on types. Honestly, someone might dispute this, but I don't think the non-generic version exists for any reasons other than backwards compatibility. I'd even be inclined to use `IEnumerable<object>` in the unlikely event of having undefined content type, just to be clear that it's intentional.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

instead of

```
IEnumerable
```

or

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
```

Answer (score 2):

You either need to

- use non-generic version of [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) which is located in `System.Collection` namespace (which you did not include)
- specify type for generic version (more likely)

Sample for generic version:

```
class TreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<T> 
{....}
```